# MVC Edit Page, Parent-Child Relationship with SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC5 EF6

I have an `Order` object that has a `Status` field. The `Order` object also has a `List<OrderLine>`. These `OrderLine`s also have a `Status` field. The status' for Order and OrderLine are different.

I have managed to display as required - I have a dropdown for the Order Status and a `<table>` containing a row for each `OrderLine` - each `OrderLine` has a dropdown for it's status - this is all displaying correctly showing the correct status. I have managed this by creating the selectLists in the Controller. An issue I had was that the `Status` field has the same name "Status" in `Order` and `OrderLine`. To get around my ViewBag items having the same names I did this for the `Order` status:

```
ViewBag.OrderStatusID = new SelectList(db.Status.Where(s => s.SystemSectionID == Utils.Enums.SystemSection.ORDER), "StatusID", "UIStatus", order.StatusID);
```

and this for the `OrderLine` status:

```
for (int x = 0; x < order.OrderLines.Count; x++)
{
    ViewData.Add("OrderLineStatusID_" + order.OrderLines.ElementAt(x).OrderLineID.ToString(), new SelectList(db.Status.Where(s => s.SystemSectionID == Utils.Enums.SystemSection.ORDER_LINE), "StatusID", "UIStatus", order.OrderLines.ElementAt(x).StatusID));
}
```

This sets up my view ensuring all Status' are showing the selected option. Here's my View:

Order part:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status.UIStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

OrderLine part: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderLines)`

```
@using Heisenberg.Extensions
@model Heisenberg.Models.OrderLine

<tr>
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("OrderLines"))
{
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderLineID)
        @Model.ProdID
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Product.TitleProduct
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("OrderLineStatusID_" + Model.OrderLineID.ToString(), null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.FulfilmentCentre.FulfilmentCentreName
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.PostageModule.PostageModuleName
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.MarketplaceSalePrice_Net
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.MarkUpAmount_Net
    </td>
}
</tr>
```

When I hit save, the Order status ID is returned so the dropdown is successfully bound to the model, Each OrderLine is returned but all fields are `null` unless I user `HiddenFor` which only returns the current Status of the OrderLine and not the one actually selected in the dropdown.

So I guess, even though the OrderLines are displayed correctly with the correct Status, the dropdown isn't actually bound to the model. I think it is due to my naming of the SelectList as I know MVC does intelligent binding based on the names - maybe its looking for the Field "OrderLineStatusID_XXX" in the OrderLine object??

Can anyone tell me the correct approach for this?

Comment: You have not shown your models. But assuming `OrderLine` has a property names `OrderLineStatusID` then it wont bind because your controls are named `OrderLineStatusID##` where `##` is the OrderLineID. As always use a view model and use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.DropDownLstFor(m => m.OrderLineStatusID, Model.StatusList)`

Comment: Hmm, I was trying to avoid a ViewModel as it would almost be exactly the same as the Model but with the select list. Having said that - it does seem to be the most appropriate method of achieving what I require. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did as @StephenMueke suggested and created a ViewModel that contained the selectLists that I required - a bit more effort but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding to your question, the OrderLineStatusID value is coming null to the controller while saving.
so,
You can assign a name to the dropdownlist using the name attribute like:

@Html.DropDownList("OrderLineStatusID" + Model.OrderLineID.ToString(), null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @name="someName" })

and use the name as a parameter in the controller to get the value.

Comment: don't use dynamic binding of id in the statement 
"+ Model.OrderLineID.ToString()" in the above statment